# Banner alignment in vbulletin using css?

Tags: php, css, vbulletin

I have a site where sponsors pay to have their own section with a banner.

However, since updating to the latest vbulletin version 4.1, i am having problems getting the homepage to look right with the banners.

If you look at the homepage of http://www.r32oc.com you will notice that the banners are being manipulated by the text title of the section they are within. Ideally i would like to get the banner to stick to the far right of that box or directly underneath the section title.

The code for the forumdisplay page is this:

```
    <!-- vBSponsors -->  
<vb:if condition="$foruminfo['sponsor_enabled'] == 1 AND $vboptions['sponsor_global_enable_sponsorship'] == 1"> 
{vb:raw vboptions.sponsor_global_default_text}  
<a href="vB.Sponsors/link.php?f={vb:raw foruminfo.forumid}" title="{vb:raw foruminfo.sponsor_name}" target="_blank">  
<vb:if condition="$foruminfo['sponsor_banner_enabled'] == 1 AND $vboptions['sponsor_global_enable_banners'] == 1"> 
<vb:if condition="!empty($foruminfo['sponsor_banner_big'])"> 
<vb:if condition="$vboptions['sponsor_global_enable_big_banners'] == 1"> 
<img src="{vb:raw foruminfo.sponsor_banner_big}" border="0" align="right" />  
<vb:else />  
<img src="{vb:raw foruminfo.sponsor_banner}" border="0" align="right" />  
</vb:if>  
<vb:else />  
{vb:raw foruminfo.sponsor_name}  
</vb:if> </vb:if> </a> </vb:if>  
<!-- / vBSponsors -->
```

---

If anyone can helpy me with this, i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 364 of the source there is a `div` beneath the `#breadcrumb` div that has the following inline style:

```
<div style="width:728px; margin:0 auto; padding-bottom:1em">
```

To change it to align left you would change `margin:0 auto;` to just `margin:0;`.  To align right you would change it to `margin:0 0 0 85px;`.

I am not familiar with vbulletin so I can't tell you where this div styling is located, however if you do a search for the `#breadcrumb div` then you are likely to find it.

Comment: brilliant mVChr, ive found exactly where I need to be thanks very much. :)